# Error after passing a string to chrome.extension.getViews()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in the background.js of my new extension,
I wish to modify popup on certain conditions,
Here is excerpts from my **background.js**

```
 windows=chrome.extension.getViews("popup").filter(
    function(w) {
              return w.location.pathname == "popup.html"}
    )[0];
```

However in the console I am **getting an error**

> Invocation of form extension.getViews(string) doesn't match
>   definition extension.getViews(optional object
>   fetchProperties)(…)normalizeArgumentsAndValidate @
>   extensions::schemaUtils:112(anonymous function) @
>   extensions::binding:411(anonymous function) @ background.js:15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for [`chrome.extension.getViews`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews) is an object rather than string, try the following:

```
chrome.extension.getViews({ type: 'popup' });
```